# Access Activity from ContentView

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I get access to the activity from it's contentView? The contentView is custom layout implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting "custom layout implementation" as your having created a custom subclass of `View`.

Any subclass of `View` can call `getContext()` which, in all normal cases, will return the `Activity` that hosts the `View`.

Comment: So, I can write Activity activity = (Activity) getContext(); ?